# Cifs mounting doesnt work

Tags: networking, samba, fstab, cifs

pretty complicated problem, i did what i can and i also had a more versed person look at it but doesnt seem to bair any fruits.

On both machines we cannot mount our network share with cifs, on other machines the same exact process works fine as well as on Windows machines in the same subnet.
/etc/fstab configured with the following lines on the bottom:

```
#DFS Drive X
//ad.mydomain.org/data /mnt/DriveX cifs user,file_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt 0 0
#subdolder
//ad.mydomain.org/data/subfolder /mnt/subfolder cifs user,file_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,vers=2.0,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt 0 0
//ad.mydomain.org/data/subfolder2 /mnt/subfolder2 cifs user,file_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt 0 0
```

/etc/credentails.txt also configured and with chmod 700

All directories mentioned created but when i enter "sudo mount -a" the system is stuck, on one machine we also get this some times:

```
Message from syslogd@wks-schl-060 at Oct 13 15:37:40 ...
 kernel:[ 2346.905732] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#34 stuck for 1926s! [migration/34:223]

Message from syslogd@wks-schl-060 at Oct 13 15:38:00 ...
 kernel:[ 2367.029834] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#79 stuck for 2004s! [cifsd:4489]
```

Here output of dmesg on cifs:

```
[  207.287549] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG has not responded in 180 seconds. Reconnecting...
[  887.247795] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  891.464229] EXT4-fs (sda): mounted filesystem a1c73175-df7b-4e2f-87f1-229141478d6e with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[  891.491923] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  958.467584] CIFS: VFS: \\ad.mydomain.org\IPC$ smb2_get_dfs_refer: ioctl error: rc=-78
[ 1040.850969] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): mounted filesystem 477b98b5-c5e6-470d-a033-36d845709d01 with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[ 1892.463967] CIFS: VFS: reconnect tcon failed rc = -11
[ 1892.465891] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[ 1892.471705] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG\IPC$ smb2_get_dfs_refer: ioctl error: rc=-13
[ 4071.728893] CIFS: VFS: reconnect tcon failed rc = -11
[ 4071.731358] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[ 4071.738955] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG\IPC$ smb2_get_dfs_refer: ioctl error: rc=-78
[ 6251.041749] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[ 6251.043897] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[ 6251.048689] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG disabling echoes and oplocks
[ 6251.048721] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[10298.322219] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[10298.330581] CIFS: VFS: reconnect tcon failed rc = -11
[10298.337341] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG\IPC$ smb2_get_dfs_refer: ioctl error: rc=-78
[14345.591042] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG Send error in SessSetup = -11
[14345.595349] CIFS: VFS: reconnect tcon failed rc = -11
[14345.599895] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG\IPC$ smb2_get_dfs_refer: ioctl error: rc=-78
[18392.848970] CIFS: VFS: reconnect tcon failed rc = -11
[18392.851997] CIFS: VFS: reconnect tcon failed rc = -11
[18392.855095] CIFS: VFS: \\SRV-x.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG\IPC$ smb2_get_dfs_refer: ioctl error: rc=-78
```

The server with the share to be mountedf is pingable and accesible from windows systems on the same subnet.
nmap says port 445 and 139 are open.

Please help me out on this one i'm genuinly out of answers hahaha